# How to create a new Xcode project with existing files?

Tags: c, git, bash, makefile, xcode3.2

Hey guys I've initially posted this both in superuser as well as programmers but I haven't gotten any replies yet, and someone suggested here, so I thought I'll ask it again here:

I'm currently using XCode 3.2, and I am already working on my existing project using the terminal and vim. Files/folders that already exists are:

- C source files
- C header files
- makefile
- bash script for automatic testing
- test directories
- git
- a library archive, most probably of C object files (if it helps it has an extension of .a)

My current program basically syncs 2 or more directories given to it as arguments in the terminal and syncs them recursively. I'm trying to use Xcode in hopes that it'll help in debugging and improving my workflow in general.

EDIT
Just to clarify I want to actually create a new Xcode project and import all my current code, makefile, git repo, testing script etc and not write the code to do it.

Comment: It looks like a tough objective: ( http://danwright.info/blog/2010/10/xcode-pbxproject-files/ ). Good luck :-)

Comment: Lol guess so, seeing how little replies I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project with the "Command Line Tool" template (select "C" as the type), and import your files.
[image]

If you want to use your Makefile instead of managing the build process via Xcode, you can create a new target with a custom build phase that'll invoke your own Makefile.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic here, but I would prefer instructions on how to do it from a blank project. That way I can learn about how to make my own targets, executable etc. Also note that I'll need to incorporate a library archive into the building process, as well as being able to specify the arguments when running.

Comment: @jon2512chua - you'd get most milage out of examining a fresh / empty Command Line Tool project, just have a look at the files it creates. (hint: creating them from scratch is a pain.)