# NetBeans doesn't recognize Makefile.am

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, netbeans, compilation

I'm coming from a Objective-C/Xcode background.

I'm used to working with C projects already imported into XCode, but now I want to analyse an existing [implementation](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/nsanch/balsa-1.2.pre2/src/balsa-index-threading.c) of an [algorithm](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) I'm interested in integrating with my project.

Only that this project is written completely in C and has nothing to do with Objective-C/Xcode etc.

I'm not sure what is the best way to view a purely [C project](http://balsa.gnome.org/git-help.html) on Mac, so I installed NetBeans for C/C++.

The problem is that when I try to create a **New Project** on NetBeans and select `C/C++ Project with Existing Sources` it complains that

```
no make files or configure scripts were found
```

in the root directory.. although it clearly has a Makefile.am

I know that the Balsa project is written for linux, but I'm not interested in building the binary I just want to look at the source code in a IDE kinda way (ie I can click on a function call and see where it's implemented etc etc).

So in short **my question is** why isn't NetBeans recognising my `Makefile.am`?

and just for reference here is the content of the `Makefile.am`

```
#intl dir needed for tarball --disable-nls build.
DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS=--disable-extra-mimeicons --without-gnome --without-html-widget
SUBDIRS = po sounds images doc libbalsa libinit_balsa src
# set tar in case it is not set by automake or make

man_MANS=balsa.1

pixmapdir = $(datadir)/pixmaps
pixmap_DATA = gnome-balsa2.png

desktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
desktop_in_files = balsa.desktop.in balsa-mailto-handler.desktop.in
desktop_DATA = balsa.desktop balsa-mailto-handler.desktop
@INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE@

balsa_extra_dist =      \
    GNOME_Balsa.server.in   \
    HACKING         \
    balsa-mail-style.xml    \
    balsa-mail.lang     \
    balsa.1.in      \
    balsa.spec.in       \
    bootstrap.sh        \
    docs/mh-mail-HOWTO  \
    docs/pine2vcard     \
    docs/vconvert.awk   \
    $(desktop_in_files) \
    gnome-balsa2.png    \
    intltool-extract.in \
    intltool-merge.in   \
    intltool-update.in  \
    mkinstalldirs

if BUILD_WITH_G_D_U
balsa_g_d_u_extra_dist = gnome-doc-utils.make
endif

if !BUILD_WITH_UNIQUE
serverdir               = $(libdir)/bonobo/servers
server_in_files         = GNOME_Balsa.server
server_DATA             = $(server_in_files:.server.in=.server)

$(server_in_files): $(server_in_files).in
    sed -e "s|\@bindir\@|$(bindir)|" $< > $@

endif

EXTRA_DIST =            \
    $(balsa_extra_dist)     \
    $(balsa_g_d_u_extra_dist)

if BUILD_WITH_GTKSOURCEVIEW2
gtksourceviewdir = $(BALSA_DATA_PREFIX)/gtksourceview-2.0
gtksourceview_DATA = balsa-mail.lang        \
    balsa-mail-style.xml
endif

DISTCLEANFILES = $(desktop_DATA) $(server_DATA) \
    intltool-extract intltool-merge intltool-update \
    gnome-doc-utils.make


dist-hook: balsa.spec
    cp balsa.spec $(distdir)

@MAINT@RPM: balsa.spec
@MAINT@ rm -f *.rpm
@MAINT@ $(MAKE) distdir="$(PACKAGE)-@BALSA_VERSION@" dist
@MAINT@ cp $(top_srcdir)/rpm-po.patch $(top_builddir)/rpm-po.patch
@MAINT@ rpm -ta "./$(PACKAGE)-@BALSA_VERSION@.tar.gz"
@MAINT@ rm $(top_builddir)/rpm-po.patch
@MAINT@ -test -f "/usr/src/redhat/SRPMS/$(PACKAGE)-@VERSION@-@BALSA_RELEASE@.src.rpm" \
@MAINT@     && cp -f "/usr/src/redhat/SRPMS/$(PACKAGE)-@VERSION@-@BALSA_RELEASE@.src.rpm" .
@MAINT@ -for ping in /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/* ; do \
@MAINT@     if test -d $$ping ; then \
@MAINT@         arch=`echo $$ping |sed -e 's,/.*/\([^/][^/]*\),\1,'` ; \
@MAINT@         f="$$ping/$(PACKAGE)-@VERSION@-@BALSA_RELEASE@.$$arch.rpm" ; \
@MAINT@         test -f $$f && cp -f $$f . ; \
@MAINT@     fi ; \
@MAINT@ done

@MAINT@snapshot:
@MAINT@ $(MAKE) distdir=$(PACKAGE)-`date +"%y%m%d"` dist

@MAINT@balsa-dcheck:
@MAINT@ $(MAKE) BALSA_DISTCHECK_HACK=yes distcheck

## to automatically rebuild aclocal.m4 if any of the macros in
## `macros/' change
bzdist: distdir
    @test -n "$(AMTAR)" || { echo "AMTAR undefined. Run make bzdist AMTAR=gtar"; false; }
    -chmod -R a+r $(distdir)
    $(AMTAR) chojf $(distdir).tar.bz2 $(distdir)
    -rm -rf $(distdir)

# macros are not used any more by current configure.in, see also
# post by Ildar Mulyukov to balsa-list, 2006.06.27
# ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I macros
```

---

### UPDATE

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030969/766570) answer.. but I got the following:

```
autoreconf --install
configure.in:250: warning: macro `AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
glibtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
glibtoolize: Remember to add `LT_INIT' to configure.in.
glibtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
glibtoolize: `AC_PROG_RANLIB' is rendered obsolete by `LT_INIT'
configure.in:250: warning: macro `AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
configure.in:249: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_INTLTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.in:250: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT
configure.in:301: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I'm looking into using the suggestions in the output..

Comment: As a longtime netbeans user, I can tell you that nb really sucks for C development. Regardless of that, you'll still need to work through these issues to move ahead.

Comment: can you please recommend an alternate Mac compatible IDE for C development?

Comment: What's wrong with XCode?

Comment: XCode doesn't recognize a C project (so to speak).. ie if you git cloen the balsa project.. and you open the directory from XCode.. you wont have a project view where for example right clicking a function will allow you to jump to it's definition etc

Comment: You will have to create an XCode project over the source.

Comment: oh i see what you're saying.. but it doesn't [seem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087916/how-to-create-a-new-xcode-project-with-existing-files) like a trivial matter.. but that's oright.. please write up your comment as an answer so that I can award you a check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per abbood's request...

Netbeans is not very good for C development. One approach would be to build an XCode project around the source base. The maintainers of the project may even accept the XCode project as a contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  I just tried downloading "balsa" and noticed that they distributed the Makefile.am and configure.in files instead of a ready to run configure script. You could let the package maintainers know they aren't doing anyone any favors by not precompiling their own autotools sources.

Makefile.am is not a real Makefile. It's the thing that generates Makefile.in, which in turn gets translated into a real Makefile by a configure script.

Try the following steps:

Download the sources to balsa again clean.  Then from the command prompt type the following:

```
autoreconf --install
```

(If you don't have autoreconf, you likely need to install the autotools packages - ughh...)

That should generate the configure script.  Then type:

```
./configure
```

It complained about some missing GMime dependencies, so I didn't see it actually generate a Makefile.  Once you get to the point in which a Makefile is generated, you should be able to point Netbeans to "open project from existing sources".

Comment: I did as you suggested.. but I got some errors.. please see updated question (i'm working on it)